# How to quickly move a tab among others in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I have opened 50+ tabs in a Firefox window. Now I would like to move one of the leftmost tabs to be the rightmost. Besides dragging the tab along the tab list, are there other ways for quick and convenient move?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](http://techie-buzz.com/how-to/move-firefox-tabs-keyboard-shortcut.html), you could install a particular FF add-on called [MoveTabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/move-tabs/), and be able to move tabs using keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you could drag it off tab bar in to its own window, scroll the original tab list and then drag it back into the list at the new location. but that seems like it would be nearly as much work